# How to fix a texture to the object it is being mapped to?

Tags: texturing

I'm new to Blender 2.8 and have been playing around with UV mapping onto objects. After following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snbEMKGOla0 I noticed that once I had added the environment texture node then reposition the sphere, the texture seems to warp as if it is still trying to map around a sphere at the global 0,0,0 coordinate. Below shows the texture before the movement and after

*Before* [image]

*After* [image]

I've also noticed that when rotating the sphere, the geometry of the sphere rotates because the 'poles' of the uv sphere move as shown below. Despite this, the texture still remains in its initial position. I am wondering if there is a way to fix the texture to the sphere when moving it, or is there a better way to achieve this in general?

*Sphere pole rotates about the x axis, however the texture remains the same* [image]

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a mapping node then a texture coordinate node?

[image]

Comment: Just tried that and got a very strange result, the texture is warped around the sphere beyond recognition. Rebuilt the sphere from scratch again and got the same result, would you have any idea what caused this? Thanks for you help, image linked here
https://imgur.com/4b0pWGG

Comment: It looks like there's an issue with the UV unwrapping. I'm able to achieve a seamless result just using the default UV for the sphere (not even touching the unwrapping, just applying the image texture with the mapping and texture coordinate nodes). Maybe look in your UV view to see how the image is being mapped?

Comment: I've played around with it for a while, it seems that contrary to the tutorial I had watched, image texture needs to be used instead of environment texture. After doing that and adding texture coordinate and mapping nodes everything works as it should. Thanks for your help @obfuscate